# how to reset Highchart chart width in percentage on Button click

Tags: highcharts

I want to change **highchart's width** on button click, I know I can do it using `chart.setSize` function, but it sets the width only in **pixels**. But I need to set the width in **percentage**.

Here is [the sample JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HMDHP/2/), in which I have tried to reset the width in 3 ways. Only Button 1 works, but not the remaining 2.

Please let me know how can I **reset** the width in **percentage**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you could do it like `button4` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/T7mtg/1/) :

```
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    var el = $('.chart-inner');
    el.css('width','100%');
    chart.setSize(el.width(),el.height(),true);
```